# TeeChart OCX still showing "Evaluation" after purchasing product

Tags: teechart

I recently purchased TeeChart ActiveX.  Everything worked great.  I recently registered the .OCX file at my client's site.  When I run my app on my development workstation, it's fine.  When I run the app on my client's site I'm getting the "Evaluation" script across the charts.  Actually, 3 out of the 4 charts show the text, one does not.  What do I need to do to address this?

I've tried deleting the 3 charts and copying the one that's ok to replace them, but they still show the the text.

Comment: You should contact the support of the vendor of TeeChart.